# Laravel 5.8 How to Retrieve Amazon S3 Path to View and Download

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, filepath

```
        $filepath = $project->logopath;
        $fullpath = "app/$filepath";

        return response()->download(storage_path($fullpath), null, []);
```

I am now getting ready for production stage, I am having issues with my files on S3 disk. I have a controller which I use to manage my uploads. Above code works fine on local disk.

I am able to upload my files to my s3 disk.

**Question:**

How can i retrieve the the correct path for my files on s3? 
I have tried;

```
            $path = Storage::disk('s3')->path($filepath);
```

Comment: How are you uploading files to s3 show the code?

Comment: ` 
$filepath = $attachment->storeAs("/logo/", $formattedname); 
`  I do this...

Comment: @eleven0 are you looking for the public URL or path? If you are looking to view/download in such case you need the public URL not path. please clarify

Comment: @VikashPathak I think I need the Public URL, I am letting the user download or view the file.

Comment: @eleven0 see my answer

Answer (score 3):

If you would like to view the s3 file. You need the public URL instead of path. You can get this like:

```
$url = Storage::disk('s3')->url($filename);
```

If you would like to available image for publically accesible.. don't forgot to pass `public` as third parameter during upload. Like:

```
Storage::disk('s3')->put($fileName, $fileContents, 'public');
```

Comment: @eleven0 let me know if it helps!

Comment: I changed the way I uploaded to this... still no good.... I can see the uploaded file via s3 console.. it says file does not exists with that URL you posted above.

Comment: Make sure your filename is correct... hopefully you are not passing the path.

Answer (score 0):

To `Store` file on `s3` you need to something like below.

let suppose i want to store some kind of logs on `s3`

```
 $path ='logs/'.$request->logs->getClientOriginalName();

     $s3 = Storage::disk('s3')->put($path,file_get_contents($request->logs),'public');

     Model::create([
     'path' => $path
     ])
```

and to get that file path you can do something like this(Which you are already doing correctly)

```
   $path = Storage::disk('s3')->path($filepath);
```

**Note: I'm using file_get_contents to stream file to s3 so that it can't cause server to leak memory in case if file is too large**

Comment: From my debug screen, i can see that path matches with I have on my s3 console. But still says file does not exists.

s3.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/{my-file-path}.... it seems correct...